# Rename many images with names from file

Tags: unix, rename

I have a file with a list of names. Let's call it nameFile. For example:

```
John Doe
John Benjamin
Benjamin Franklin
...
```

I also have a folder of pictures. The pictures are named like:

```
pic001.jpg
pic002.jpg
pic003.jpg
...
```

I want to rename each picture with the corresponding name from the nameFile. Thus, pic001.jpg will become 'John Doe.jpg', pic002.jpg will become 'John Benjamin.jpg', etc.

Is there an easy UNIX command to do this? I know mv can be used to rename, I'm just a bit unsure how to apply it to this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly people do it by  writing a simple shell script.

These two links will help you to do it.

[Bulk renaming of files in unix](http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/bulk-renaming-of-files-in-unix.html)

[Rename a group of files with one command](https://superuser.com/questions/8716/rename-a-group-of-files-with-one-command)

The `mv` is a Unix command that renames one or more files or directories. The original filename or directory name is no longer accessible. Write permission is required on all directories and files being modified.

**mv command syntax**

You need to use the mv command to rename a file as follows:

```
mv old-file-name new-file-name
mv file1 file2
mv source target
mv [options] source target
```